Pimcore Data Importer: Mapping Select Field Values from Excel with Options Provider
I'm facing challenges mapping a select field named "colorway" in Pimcore's Data Importer. I'm importing data from an Excel file, where the "colorway" column contains the colorway name.
In Pimcore, the "colorway" select field is configured using an Options Provider  \App\Lib\OptionProviders\GeneralOptionsProvider with the following configuration:
{"class": "Colorway","key": "name","value": "id","extra": "","orderKey":"name","order":"asc"}

This means the select field expects the colorway object's ID as its value. However, the Data Importer's "Load DataObject" transformation pipeline returns the entire colorway object when I map the field.
How can I modify the mapping or the transformation pipeline so that the Data Importer correctly assigns the colorway object's ID to the select field?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Pimcore version: 11.2.3.3
Data Importer version: 1.8
Excel file format: xlsx

Data Importer Configuration

Class Configuration for colorway field

